# c# Powershell exchange multi valued cmd parameter passing

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I want to run the following in a c# loop but I just don't know how to pass a multi value for a parameter with a comma. The actual cmdlet would be below and does work in exchange powershell:

Set-CalendarProcessing –ResourceDelegates jonDoe@test.com,johnnydoe@test.com -identity testroom@test.com –AutomateProcessing AutoUpdate

I know my code connection works but it's the "–ResourceDelegates jonDoe@test.com,johnnydoe@test.com" I don't know how to pass, shown below:

Sample part of the code is here:

```
command.AddCommand("Set-CalendarProcessing");
command.AddParameter("-ResourceDelegates", "userA@test.com,userB@test.com");
command.AddParameter("-Identity", "test@test.com");
command.AddParameter("-AutomateProcessing", "AutoUpdate");
```

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
command.AddParameter("ResourceDelegates", new string[] { "a@b.c", "b@d.f" });
```

Ergo, do **not** prefix the parameter name with a hyphen and pass an array if you need multiple arguments for the parameter.

Comment: what's the best way to pass an array through as an argument, can you do PassArray(array)?

Comment: I don't understand. My example is passing a string[] array.